# Clear particular column values in DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have data table with Four fields `Emp_No, AmountPaid, Amount_Adjusted, Adjustment_Reason`

I want to clear the values of `Adjustment_Reason` column

I have tried the below code :

```
for (int i = adjustmentTable.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  adjustmentTable.Rows[i]["AdjustmentReason"] = DBNull.Value;
}
```

*Its working fine.* **But** can any one suggest me a code to achieve this by using LINQ

Comment: This should not be done by `LINQ` because we have to **return** something with a `LINQ query`, however to clear the values, we don't need any value to be returned.

Answer (score 4):

You can write something like this:

```
adjustmentTable.Rows
               .OfType<DataRow>()
               .ToList()
               .ForEach(r => r["AdjustmentReason"] = DBNull.Value);
```

But quite frankly I'm not sure how performant this can be for the large amount of data in your datatable.

Comment: @TechDo

...ForEach(r => { r["ColumnA"] = "A"; r["ColumnB"] = "B"; });

If this is what you mean...